# python code dont delete all same entries in the array over an regex search function

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

i read an txt file with syslog stuff

```
Oct  3 12:09:01 webv2 CRON[1903]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/security/py_scripts/security_stuff.py 01_report_connections 0 &)
Oct  3 12:09:01 webv2 CRON[1906]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Oct  3 12:09:03 webv2 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
...
..
.
```

in an array named **data** (= insert len 6800)

```
data = string.splitlines()
```

,which should be filtered by an regex array

```
regexArray = [
  ['CRON:', [
     'sec_stuff\.py report_cons'
    ,'\[ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean \] && if \[ ! -d /run/systemd/system \]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi'
    ,'...'
    ,'..'
    ,'.'
    ]
  ],
  [...] 
]
```

over an normal function called

```
def search_regexStuff(what, strings, regexString = ''):
  if what == 'allgemein':
    return re.findall(r""+regexString+"",strings)
```

,but the problem is, he found and delete only a part of each found regex stuff in the **data** array.

as example, for regex:

```
sec_stuff\.py report_cons
```

i have 2069 entries, but he delete in the data array only 1181. for other regex stuff is the same problem. for:

```
\[ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean \] && if \[ ! -d /run/systemd/system \]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi
```

he found and delete 59 of 68

scope of that action is: i want to decrease the data len of that data array in each loop over pop or del to speed up the loop for the search. the rest of data array i write it in an other file. i cant find my fail why my code will not work. cant see the fail. =( plz help. thx

code:

```
for b in regexArray:
  for c in b[1]:
    regex = '.*'+b[0][:-1]+'.*'+c+'.*'
    n = -1
    for a in data:
      n += 1
      findLINE = search_regexStuff('allgemein', a, regex)
      if len(findLINE) != 0: # found returned arraay not empty
        del data[n]
        n -= 1
o = ''
for i in data:
  o += i+'\n'
file = open('/folder/file_x.txt','w')
file.write(str(o))
file.close()
```

### UPDATE (solution) and thx @timus:

i defined an extra function who throws me the new data array out to solve that problem

```
def cleanMyDataArray( data, regex):
o = ''; new_data = []
for a in data:
  findLINE = search_regexStuff('allgemein', a, regex)
  if len(findLINE) == 0: # not found
    new_data.append( a )
return new_data
```

@code:

```
for b in regexArray:
  for c in b[1]:
    regex = '.*'+b[0][:-1]+'.*'+c+'.*'
    data = cleanMyDataArray( data, regex)
```

thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a classic mistake: You remove items from a list while iterating over it. That tends to go south. Also, modifying a list with `del` is usually not very efficient.

Example: A list `numbers` from which you want to remove the even numbers. Your method

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = -1
for a in numbers:
    n += 1
    if a % 2 == 0:
        del numbers[n]
        n -= 1
print(numbers)
```

results in `[1, 4, 5]`, which is obviously wrong. Why does that happen:

1. Step: The first number is odd, so nothing happens, and `n` becomes `0`.
2. Step: The next item `2` is even, so the list gets modified to `[1, 3, 4, 5]`, and `n` stays `0`.
3. Step: Now the iteration grabs the item with *index* `2`, which is `4`. Since it is even and `n` is `0 + 1 == 1` the item `3` gets removed, the list is `[1, 4, 5]` now, and `n` stays `0`.
4. Step: The remaining list has length `3`, so no item with *index* `3`, thus the iteration stops.

How to fix this? Create a new list, ideally with a list comprehension:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers = [a for a in numbers if not a % 2 == 0]
print(numbers)
```

Result: `[1, 3, 5]`

Beyond that: You could use the pattern

```py
for b in regexArray:
    regex = b[0][:-1] + '.*(' + '|'.join(b[1]) + ').*'
```

instead of iterating over `b[1]`. But there are some odd parts in your use of regex:

- Why do you close your patterns with `.*`?
- Why do you use `re.findall` instead of `re.search`?
- Do you really use `'...'`, `'..'`, `'.'` instead of `'\.\.\.'` etc.? A pattern like `CRON.*....*` matches anything that has at least 3 characters after `CRON` -- is that what you want?

Comment: thx. yeah i know it now that delete out of the same array is not the best idea, but i thought, because the rest of the information which i need to delete over(del or pop) is in front of the loop, i could handle that over that n -= 1 form. but your modulo form explain/shows really well the problem, that i have and explain that 1181 of 2069. also the missing information in the array. now i change it (see update) where the information without the found stuff is stored in an new array, which works like a charm.

Comment: for me is not logical, why the for loop or del/pop function works as it works, but however. good that it exists many ways to solve such kind of problems. @1.dot) because it could be also be some or not text behint the searched word. @2.dot) why should be search better then findall in that case? sry realtive new at regex and python stuff. @3.dot) oh yeah i could use also ... or .. for that spaces but i thought with .* is all of that between breakets [] or between searched words. but if you mean ... or .. or . at the the array. it means only etc. or it stands for etc. -> ...\n..\n. == etc.

Comment: @wtf_1x Thanks for the feedback. Regarding the regex points: (1) I still don't think the `.*` at the end makes a difference in identifying the matches you are looking for. Maybe try it without them to check. (2) `re.findall` works, but it's primarily designed to to find multiple matches in one string. `re.search` just checks if there's at least one match - and that seems more like what you're intending to do. (3) Depends on what you want to achieve: `.` is a special character within a regex pattern, it won't only match a literal dot but all characters.